# Appending variables to a string in javascript

Tags: javascript, prototype

I am using prototype in my application but I am not sure how to add this correctly. Basically I have the following function and I need to construct the href of an anchor from which I already have the reference to a series of appended values

```
MyJavascriptClass.prototype.init = function() {
    this.ToDate = $(this.Prefix + 'ToDate');
    this.FromDate = $(this.Prefix + 'FromDate');
}
```

so in the following function I need to add those as parameters in the url attribute

```
MyJavascriptClass.prototype.btnClicked = function(evt) {

this.lnkShowLink.setAttribute('href', 'MyWebpage.aspx?StartDate=7/18/2012&EndDate=1/19/2012');

}
```

How can i do something like  `'MyWebPage.aspx?StartDate=this.ToDate&EndDate=this.FromDate'` ? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using jquery, and `$(this.Prefix + 'ToDate')` and `$(this.Prefix + 'FromDate')` represent fields that contain values, then you can do this:

```
MyJavascriptClass.prototype.btnClicked = function(evt) {
    this.lnkShowLink.setAttribute('href', 'MyWebpage.aspx?StartDate=' + this.ToDate.val() + '&EndDate=' + this.FromDate.val() + '');
}
```

It is difficult to tell from your code what they represent, and why you have them wrapped in `$(..)`.

Answer (score 0):

If ToDate and FromDate contain the two date values, then this should work...

```
'MyWebPage.aspx?StartDate=' + this.ToDate + '&EndDate=' + this.FromDate
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know every properties:

```
var properties = [];
for(var i in this)
    if(this.hasOwnProperty(i))
        properties.push(i+'='+this[i]);
var url = 'MyWebPage.aspx?'+properties.join('&');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var string = "My name is: ",
    name = "Bob",
    punctuation = ".",


greeting = string + name + punctuation;
```

Or

```
var User = { name : "Bob", age : 32, sign : "Leo" },
welcome = "Hi, I'm " + User.name + ", and I'm " + User.age + " years old, I'm a " + User.sign + ", and I enjoy long walks on the beach.";
```